# Подгрузка моделей с пустыми отношениями

Tags: sql, laravel, запрос, eloquent, querybuilder

я делаю фильтрацию модели по отношению через with.

```
$query->with(['user' => function ($query) use ($filters) {
   ///Тут фильтрация
}]);
```

У каждой модели есть отношение user, мне просто нужно отфильтровать эти модели и выбрать из них те, у которых это отношение проходит фильтр. Если оставить так, то выведутся все модели, просто у некоторых будет user => null в подгруженном отношении (relations).
Мне же нужно чтобы такие модели не подгружались, если делать has(), то он делает запрос на существование прикрепленного user к этой модели, но он всегда будет существовать, поэтому это никак не помогает убрать такие модели из подгрузки. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фильтр для отношений делается таким образом:

```
$query->with('user')->whereHas('user', function($q) use ($filters) {

});
```

Comment: Благодарю, это действительно самое адекватное решение.